# RaspberryPi getting error after reading some serial Input, using rs232 and C Language

Tags: raspbian, c, wiringpi

my raspberry keep getting error after reading some serial input, like this:

[image]

i'm using Library wiringPi with this sample code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <errno.h>

#include <wiringSerial.h>

int main ()
{
  int fd ;

  if ((fd = serialOpen ("/dev/ttyS0", 9600)) < 0)
  {
    fprintf (stderr, "Unable to open serial device: %s\n", strerror (errno)) ;
    return 1 ;
  }

// Loop, getting and printing characters

  for (;;)
  {
    putchar (serialGetchar (fd)) ;
    fflush (stdout) ;
  }
}
```

And I'm using Max Rs232 Module for connection from my device to raspberry pi.
why this is happend? and what must I do with this error?

Comment: the top picture of `-1-1-1-1 ....` ... is that the input?   ...... what error are you getting?

Comment: That's error I get at raspberrypi. after some period, my console suddenly getting -1-1-1-1 ... output. and this output never end.

Comment: how do you know that it is an error? .... maybe that is the data.

Comment: Because, I already try to pull out the cable from Tx, Rx, and command line still didn't stop showing -1-1-1-1-1-1 ... forever.

Comment: It's happend after some period.
even I send data 1 time, after some period its happend and wont stop until I terminate the terminal.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Revise your for(;;) loop to include if(serialDataAvail...) first. 
Also modify the loop to check the serilGetchar timeout. 
Your code is doing what it suppose to do, it is just too simple LOL!

```
int   serialDataAvail (int fd) ;
```

Returns the number of characters available for reading, or -1 for any error condition, in which case errno will be set appropriately.

```
int serialGetchar (int fd) ;
```

Returns the next character available on the serial device. This call will block for up to 10 seconds if no data is available (when it will return -1)

```
void serialFlush (int fd) ;
```

Comment: Oke thanks give me some time to try this. thanks for your advice, I will post my code ASAP.

Comment: No hurry, I am about to go to bed - it is 23:00 here ! Best of luck.

Comment: Thanks bro, and Im sorry for bad question because im i'm kinda new at C language. I usually using Python, but I want explore and learn more about C/C++ language. thanks mate.

Comment: Even I try to use serialDataAvail (fd), and serialFlush (fd), i still get error -1-1-1-1-1 sometime get square question mark. I dont Know what happend, maybe im going to re install my raspberry pi, and im going to update my question later.

Comment: Well it is your call. You original code was OK, just "too simple". It should not made OS to misbehave.  Good luck.